# how to avoid multiple p5.js sketches to run all at once

Tags: p5.js

I have a web page which encloses a few sketches, all written in P5.JS

Each sketch uses its own name space, so that it runs independently from the others.

I noticed that, for each sketch, the level of performance is lower than the one I get when it runs alone in a separate web page.

My question : what can I do to prevent all the sketches to run all at once ? Is it possible, for example, to activate a sketch only when the mouse hovers its canvas ? It would probably spare ressources.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `noLoop()` and `loop()` to stop and restart a sketch. There aren't any built in p5.js events to help you trigger `noLoop()` when the mouse leaves the sketch or when the sketch is scrolled off screen, however there are a couple of ways you can do it which rely on using the underlying browser functionality:

1. The built in `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events
2. Checking `winMouseX` and `winMouseY` against the sketch canvas `getBoundingClientRect()` in each call to `draw()`

```js
function makeSketch(...colorArgs) {
  return (p) => {
    let bgColor;
    let black;
    let c;
    p.setup = () => {
      c = p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight / 3);
      bgColor = p.color(...colorArgs);
      black = p.color(0);
      
      c.elt.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
        p.loop();
      });
      c.elt.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
        p.noLoop();
      });
      
      let bounds = c.elt.getBoundingClientRect();
      
      // Just in case the mouse is already over the canvas when it is created.
      // This is also how you would use getBoundingClientRect from the draw()
      // and mouseMoved() functions instead of the mouseenter/mouseleave events.
      if (p.winMouseX < bounds.left ||
        p.winMouseX > bounds.right ||
        p.minMouseY < bounds.top ||
        p.winMouseY > bounds.bottom) {
        
        p.noLoop();
      }
    };
    
    p.draw = () => {
      p.background(p.lerpColor(
        bgColor,
        black,
        p.abs((p.frameCount % 240 - 120) / 120)
      ));
      
      
      let bounds = c.elt.getBoundingClientRect();
      p.fill('white');
      p.noStroke();
      p.text(`${p.winMouseX}, ${p.winMouseY} :: ${bounds.left}, ${bounds.top}, ${bounds.right}, ${bounds.bottom}`, 10, 10); 
    }
  };
}

let sketch1 = new p5(makeSketch('red'));
let sketch2 = new p5(makeSketch(0, 255, 0));
let sketch3 = new p5(makeSketch('blue'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```

You might also find that it is sufficient to pause sketches that are off screen:

```js
function makeSketch(...colorArgs) {
  return (p) => {
    let bgColor;
    let black;
    let c;
    let isLooping;
    p.setup = () => {
      c = p.createCanvas(p.windowWidth, p.windowHeight);
      bgColor = p.color(...colorArgs);
      black = p.color(0);
      
      let bounds = c.elt.getBoundingClientRect();
      
      isLooping = true;
      if (bounds.bottom < 0 ||
          bounds.top > p.windowHeight) {
        
        p.noLoop();
        isLooping = false;
      }
      
      // Might need to check this on resize as well.
      document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        let bounds = c.elt.getBoundingClientRect();
        // Note this only checks verticle scrolling, but you could check horizontal as well
        if (bounds.bottom > 0 &&
            bounds.top <= p.windowHeight) {

          if (!isLooping) {
            isLooping = true;
            console.log(`sketch ${colorArgs.join(',')}: loop`);
            p.loop();
          }
        } else if (isLooping) {
          isLooping = false;
          console.log(`sketch ${colorArgs.join(',')}: noLoop`);
          p.noLoop();
        }
      });
    };
    
    p.draw = () => {
      p.background(p.lerpColor(
        bgColor,
        black,
        p.abs((p.frameCount % 240 - 120) / 120)
      ));
      
      p.fill('white');
      p.noStroke();
      p.text(`${p.frameCount}`, 10, 10);
    }
  };
}

let sketch1 = new p5(makeSketch('red'));
let sketch2 = new p5(makeSketch(0, 255, 0));
let sketch3 = new p5(makeSketch('blue'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```